# Modeling error while booting jar-package with matlab model

Tags: java, matlab, simulink

I have a matlab model, which I recompiled to the java package (jar). On my computer's host system it works fine, but ... When I am trying to run it in docker container under ubuntu, I am getting an error:

-->Converting the "Model.Plant" property of "mpc" object to state-space.
-->Converting model to discrete time.
Error using mpc/getStruct (line 304)
The "c2d" command cannot be used for models of class "ss".

Error in mpc/sim (line 49)

Error in CalcMPCLib (line 14)

The "c2d" command cannot be used for models of class "ss".

Line 14 - try to use "sim" function. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: What toolboxes are you using?  It's not clear from the error you've shown whether you are using any Simulink functionality (from within the MPC Toolbox), and if not, why you've used the Simulink Tag.  But if you are using Simulink then note that Simulink is not supported by the MATLAB Compiler (and hence cannot be converted to standalone use.)

Comment: yes, as far as i know, sim - is a function of the simulink. it is really bad ... so, if i want to use this jar in docker container, i need to find the way how to install the simulink into the container? but compiler doesn't say, that it can't find the function, it seems like the function was found, but he said that class of one of variables is wrong ...

Comment: Many objects have a `sim` function, so it isn't necessarily the `sim` of a Simulink model, which is why I asked you to clarify.

Comment: MPC control toolbox, as far as I understand... I can show you the code, If it is possible here or anywere else ... May be it will clarify problem conditions